# pythonic swap x,y = y,x doesn't work?

Tags: python, swap

I just realized that the pythonic swap doesn't always work.

```
def swap(x,y):
    x,y = y,x

a = 1
b = 2
swap(a,b)

print b
```

result: 2

Why does the pythonic way to swap variables not work in this case? Do I need temporary a variable?

Comment: what exactly do you expect? `print b` will indeed print `2` becuase `b=2`

Comment: most python objects are non mutable ... ergo you are not actually swapping ... you are just creating a local x,y variable inside the function such that `x=y,y=x` but it only holds true while you are in the method scope

Comment: @JoranBeasley this has nothing to do with mutability. The behaviour would be the same if you had passed in lists for this function.

Comment: `x[:] = x[::-1]` @timgeb ... but yeh I know what you are saying

Comment: @hongjooy, has your question been answered?

Answer (score 4):

In the first line of the function definition

```
def swap(x,y):
```

`x` and `y` are so called *formal parameters*.
When you call

```
swap(a, b)
```

you are passing in `a` and `b` as *actual arguments*.

What happens now is that Python creates new names for the actual arguments you have passed in.

Inside the function body `x` is now a new name for the integer object in memory which also has the name `a`. `y` is now a new name for the integer object in memory which also goes by the name `b`. This is why Python is neither call-by-value nor call-by-reference, but best described as [call-by-assignment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns#t=21m20s).

Contrary to popular belief, calling functions and assignment works exactly the same way for mutable and immutable parameters. You will see the same behavior you are observing for mutable values:

```
>>> def swap(x,y):
...     x,y = y,x
... 
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = [2]
>>> swap(a,b)
>>> a
[1]
>>> b
[2]
```

So once you understand how assignments work in Python, you will also have understood how function calls work.

To make an example: If you did not write a function, your code would have been equivalent to:

```
a = 1
b = 2
x = a
y = b
x,y = y,x
del x
del y
```

In line 3, you are creating a new name `x` for the integer object which also goes by the name `a`. Line 4 follows the same logic.

In line 5, you are creating the tuple `(y, x)` with the value `(2, 1)` on the right hand side, which is then unpacked, i.e. the name `x` is *reassigned* to the value 2 and the name `y` is reassigned to the value 1:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> x = a
>>> y = b
>>> x,y = y,x
>>> x
2
>>> y
1
```

The important thing to note here is that `a` and `b` never stopped to be names for the value 1 and 2 respectively:

```
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
```

The last two lines just unbind the names `x` and `y` which is roughly equivalent to what happens in your function once you exit its scope. Note that the names `a` and `b` are still bound after unbinding `x` and `y`.

```
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You never returned and assigned the results. Otherwise, as Joran said, you are only creating local variables in the function. For example:

```
def swap(a, b):
    print "swap called"
    return (b,a)

a = 1
b = 2

print a,b
a,b = swap(a,b)
print a,b
```

Results in the following being displayed:

```
1 2
swap called
2 1
```

Comment: In other words, python is pass-by-value.

Comment: @JamesBuck no, python is pass-by-assignment.

Comment: @timgeb it's pass-by-value in the same way that C and Java are. More accurately described as pass-by-reference-value.

Comment: @JamesBuck please watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns#t=21m20s), nobody calls it like that in python, for good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something; the swapped vars